# Sum by one field, but only for unique ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, distinct, aggregate-functions

I need to sum a sales quantity by month and year, but my database has some duplicate entries.  I know this is not ideal, but it is a government database, so I cannot fix it.  The database has a large number of records (> 200 million) so I don't want to group by the ID.

Here is essentially what I want to do:

```
select YEAR(begin_date) as yr, MONTH(begin_date) as mnth, SUM(quantity) as quant 
from Table
[where transactionID is unique]
group by YEAR(begin_date), MONTH(begin_date)
order by YEAR(begin_date), MONTH(begin_date)
```

The resulting data should look like this, but not include duplicates:

```
yr  mnth    quant
2009    10  91241
2009    11  23650
2009    12  37006
2010    1   19770
2010    2   19937
2010    3   14403
```

Comment: Do you want to exclude  entries that have duplicates?

Comment: ... or do you want the first entry by date?

Comment: I want to exclude entries that are duplicates (by transactionID), but I want to sum and group by month and year.

Comment: @jczannis: do you want to exlude all rows which transactionID  is not unique or do you want to count only one row (if so, which?)? What is the primary key of the table?

Comment: I want to count only one row.  The transactionID is not the primary key, but it is what I can use to determine duplicates.  It exists more than once for some records.

Comment: It sounds to me like you want the `MAX(TransactionID)`

Comment: I don't think MAX(TansactionID) will work.  I want the data associated with all of the TransactionID's, but I only want it once for each TransactionID.

Comment: Does your table have a primary key? Like and INT IDENTITY column?

Comment: Yes, it has a primary key, and has another transactionID field that is supposed to be unique, but is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an inner-select for remove duplicate transactionIDs that are repeated in a month of a year, like this:

```
SELECT [year], [month], SUM(quantity)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT 
          YEAR(begin_date) as [year], MONTH(begin_date) as [month], MAX(quantity) as [quantity], transactionID
      FROM yourTable 
      GROUP BY
          YEAR(begin_date) as [year], MONTH(begin_date), transactionID ) DT
GROUP By [year], [month]
ORDER BY [year], [month]
```

Comment: Thanks.  This pointed me in the direction of the correct answer.  I want the sum of the quantity, not just the max.  Here's what worked: `select YEAR(dte), MONTH(dte), SUM(quant)
from (select distinct begin_date as dte, quantity as quant, transactionID
   from Table) DT
group by YEAR(dte), MONTH(dte)
order by YEAR(dte), MONTH(dte)`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your table has a primary key that is unique, you can use a CTE to determine the duplicates and just pick one to use. I also support a database that has some design problems and use this trick alot to filter out dupes.

```
;with uniques AS (PK,Number) (
    SELECT
        PrimaryKey,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY YEAR(begin_date),MONTH(begin_date) ORDER BY YEAR(begin_date)) as number
    FROM Table
)
select YEAR(begin_date) as yr, MONTH(begin_date) as mnth, SUM(quantity) as quant 
from Table t
INNER JOIN uniques u
    ON u.pk = t.PrimaryKey
    AND u.number = 1
group by YEAR(begin_date), MONTH(begin_date)
order by YEAR(begin_date), MONTH(begin_date)
```

Comment: That's a creative solution, and I think it would have worked on a smaller table.  I ran one month as a test, and after it had been running about 15 minutes, I killed it.  I must admit I didn't understand what you were doing, so I spent some time reading about the over partition.  If nothing else, I've leaned something new.  Thanks for your help.